# Dynamic posts loading with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I've been trying to make a blog system but I've got lost at some point. The posts get generated in this format: posts/today/today.xml (for example: posts/2014-08-19/2014-08-19.xml) The xml contains the image's name, the title and the date when it was made. It's okay if I want to load today's posts, there's no problem with that but the main problem is about the posts loading which are older than a day.

I've got a function in ajax which loads the xml the only parameter it needs is the url to the xml. Let's call it loadPost(url).
I made the formatting purposely so I'd like to keep that.
I couldn't find a way to load it dynamically with php because after the php brackets are executed the variables delete right ? Or shall I use global variables ?
Now it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        loadPost('posts/<?php echo $nextpost.'/'.$nextpost ?>.xml');
        <?php
        $nextpost = date ('Y-m-d',strtotime( '-1 day' , strtotime ($nextpost)));
        echo $nextpost;
        ?>
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm in really need for help, anybody got an idea how to go on ?
Thanks in advance !

EDIT:
This is called in the first few lines in index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['dayCounter'] = 0;
$today = date("Y-m-d", time());
$nextpost = date ('Y-m-d',strtotime( '-1 day' , strtotime ($today)));
```

?>

Comment: You have two variables `$nexpost` and `$nextpost`. Where is `$nextpost` coming from in your call to `strtotime`?

Comment: edited in the post :)

Comment: woah, that was a typo, but still it only loads $nextpost post. It doesn't subtract from it in the php code, which is after the loadPost(url) function.

Comment: If the second block of code you have there comes before the first one, it looks like `$nextpost` in `loadPost('posts/<?php echo $nextpost.'/'.$nextpost ?>.xml');` will always be yesterday.

Comment: even if I access it from another block and change it's value it won't matter ?

Comment: Not if that block comes after the point at which you're outputting it to the page.

Comment: then how can I dynamically access and change $nextpost so I can subtract another day from it ?

Comment: so, i should say that i don't think you're going about this the right way, but it looks like an experiment, so ... maybe your best bet is to use cookies. 1) check if a particular cookie exists, if it doesn't, show the most recent post and set the cookie to that date string. If the cookie does exist, subtract a day from it, reset the cookie and use that to show your post.

Comment: Ye, that's what I was thinking of too!